# fake/automate a "hover" in JavaScript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to put this nav bar on my website, here is the demonstration page: http://insicdesigns.com/demo/css3/exp1/index.html
it uses JavaScript, jQuery, and CSS

The problem is, on my site I use PHP and a **index.php?page=home**, **?index.php?page=contact**, etc.
And I can't figure out how to set an item on the bar as "active" [it defaults to "Home"]. I looked into the code, and I found out that the first <li> [the Home] has *class="active"*. I tried simply moving the class to the second item, ["About"] but that just screws everything up, by moving the whole animation to the right which does not work as it is meant to. So on the .click(), this is how it sets an item active:

```
$(this).siblings('li').removeClass('active'); // removes active
$(this).addClass('active');
```

So I put *id="target"* on another item, and with Chrome's JS Console I type in the same code, except I use *"#target"* instead of *"this"*
But nothing immediately changes. I have to *hover* over the bar, for the animation to start, look for the active item, and move the animation over there. Right now, if I use this to replace my current nav bar [which is [here](http://www.macdonaldfamilysingers.com)], and if someone goes to `index.php?page=contact` I can't make the About link active so that the user knows they're on the `About` page!

So here is my question:
Is there a way to tell jQuery I just hovered, from some code? [fool it]
something like:

```
$("#target").fakeEvent("hover");
```

So that it runs the code [which, btw, is attached to a function(){} inside a $(selector).hover() -- look at the lavalamp.js file on the example]? If you can help, I'd really appreciate it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer: http://jsfiddle.net/morrison/4CU4H/**

**Notes on answer:**

- [The fancy menu](http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2010/02/creating-a-fancy-menu-using-css3-and-jquery/) uses poor JavaScript. I have adapted the script to fix some bugs as well as optimize performance. **Use my JavaScript instead of theirs.**
- To get the active class in the correct position on page-load, simply apply the active class where you would like before jQuery is called.  You should probably **set the active class in your php output.** This also allows for nice style degradation when JavaScript won't load.
- The plug-in disables clicking because it's an example.  You'll probably want to **remove the return statement in the click function**.

**Notes on your website:**

- **Hide your queries.**  This isn't a hard rule, but in your case you should.  `http://www.macdonaldfamilysingers.com/?page=contactindex.php?page=contact` should be `http://www.macdonaldfamilysingers.com/contact/`.  Here's [a tutorial on url rewriting](http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/).
- You'll probably want to **beautify your tables**.  By removing some of the borders and spacing, it'll also take up less visual space.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on url rewriting... however, they do not seem to work on my local Apache2 server [Ubuntu 11.04 x64], probably my configuration; however, if I can't get it to work on `localhost` then it will make developing very difficult! :P [It does work on my Remote server, however.] And another complication is, I'd have to use a rewrite engine for every page that needs a &variable=value, like, the page "schedule" which optionally takes a &year=2012, or whichever year. [you can still rewrite the URL, but it seems it'd just make things more complicated] Will try your modified code now

Comment: It's not that hard, really.  In fact, it makes it simpler: `/schedule/2012/` vs `?page=contact&year=2012`  If it's the rule complication that worries you, it's also easy (untested): `RewriteRule ^schedule/([0-9]*)/?$ /?page=schedule&year=$1 [L,NC]`.  Basically, you treat rules that require specific values, then do a generic rule for what's left.

Comment: oh.. well I will think about doing it.. but it's not just that one page. I do not remember if I used more &vars=vals in my contact, or whichever pages. I could always dig in my code and look.. *anyway* ... I copy the JS, CSS, and HTMl from the URL you posted, and it does not work. It does, however, animate in the "Result" box of the URL. It's weird, I can't figure out why it doesn't work when I put it on my server. Edit: I've uploaded it to here: http://www.macdonaldfamilysingers.com/matt/menu_test/

Comment: Upload it somewhere so I can see what you are doing wrong.  The code obviously works because the jsfiddle does.

Comment: http://www.macdonaldfamilysingers.com/matt/menu_test/
btw, I meant *"I can't figure out why it doesn't work on my **local** server"*
and btw, I think you accidentally pasted the menu bar twice. So I will remove one iteration

Comment: No, the menu bar was supposed to be there twice.  It illustrates a bug found in the actual plugin.  I had it there to verify that my code fixed it.  Additionally it shows that it works properly for menus that have the active class in various positions.  As for your problem... move `js.js` to the bottom of your file, just before `</body>`.   That fixes it, mate.  Scripts belong at the bottom, for your information.

Comment: Oh right. Now it works... Btw, it says `js.js: 35Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of null` in chrome's console... [I think after clicking] Is this anything to worry about?just re-uploaded. And, um, how does this fix anything? I tried the same method (remove class, then add class on a different button. and nothing changes?? how am I supposed to change the 'active'?)

Comment: I am aware.  It happens sometimes.  It's part of the original plug-in.  If the error bothers you (it doesn't affect functionality), then simply check to make sure offset() is not null before accessing left.

Comment: ok, nah I guess I don't care about a null error. But anyway, I asked how I change the active button? I tried the method I was using [before you wrote this modified version] but it did not work

Comment: You don't, really.  You simply have the active class be on the item you want it to be on when the page loads.  You can do that by putting it there before the script loads (I don't recommend), or by hard-coding it in the php output (recommended).  The latter option allows for nice css styling even with JavaScript disabled.

Comment: ohhh, duh! I don't know why I didn't try that before. lol. Thanks very much for all your help! And btw, about the tables, do you mean remove the green rounded border off the schedule [and music] tables?

Comment: Well... change that color maybe, but I'm talking more like each individual cell (ie `A Shelter in the Time of Storm` or look at each row in the schedules page).  Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/morrison/4CU4H/9/

Comment: You know, you might have something there! After I get this Navbar switched in for the old Navbar, I will look into changing my table's look. Actually on my local server, I have gotten rid of the green tiled background, replaced it with a light blue, and put a `box-shadow` of darker blue around the "#page".. It's gonna look so much better. :)

Comment: To be honest, I'm a User-Interface/User eXperience designer/developer.  Your site drives me crazy :)  I'd gladly help you redesign the thing properly, and I don't just mean how it looks, but how it's made.

Comment: Really? well that would be cool... want to switch to email or something, I think it would be easier then keep refreshing this question to check for a reply.  here's a picture of what I have on localhost: http://img508.imageshack.us/img508/791/screenshot2wp.png besides the wrong-color green banner, is this better then what I've got now?

Comment: Better, yes.  Good... no, lol.  Feel free to email me: levi _at_ wddb.com

Answer (score 5):

Well, `hover` consist of two events, `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

You can trigger the `mouseenter` event with:

```
$("#target").mouseenter();
```

Comment: I almost gave this the thumbs up because it does, in fact, answer his question.  However, upon investigation I noticed that the plug-in is buggy and needed some adjustment.  I'd rather not have his problem solved just to have another problem arise.

Comment: Cool! This *does* answer my question. If I cannot get Levi's answer to correctly work, I will TU your post. Btw, when I **check** a post, what does that mean?

Comment: I added this code right before </body>, to change the active button to another. It works fine on Chrome. however on Firefox, it makes the whole animation offset, so the slider goes *way* to the right. So I put the code in a setTimeout(function(){code},100) and it seems to fix this error.